# How to change div by clicking on field in the menu in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have menu with some fields. And I want to change div by clicking on any field.

Default div is: #OLD_DIV

If i press any partner in menu, then #OLD_DIV will change to #NEW_DIV
[image]

Also i have to send Partner_ID to #NEW_DIV, so if I would already have selected a partner and i will click on another partner in menu, then #NEW_DIV will stay but with new Partner_ID

---

I already did that, but I think it can be done better, nicer, with better practice?

My menu and divs (jade template):

```
[...]
li#dropdown.panel.panel-default.content_wrapper.active(ng-repeat="partner in partnerList") 
     a(data-toggle='collapse', href='#dropdown-' + '{{ partner._id }}', ng-click="changeDiv(partner._id)")
          {{ partner.name }}
[...]

#old_div(ng-show="display")
| some stuff, forms. etc
[...]

#new_div(ng-show="!display")
| some stuff, forms. etc
[...]
```

Angular script:

```
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http){
        $scope.display = true;

        $scope.changeDiv = function(id){
        $scope.partnerId = id;
        $scope.display = !$scope.display
        }
        });
```

Comment: you could do this with the router switching templates when clicking on a name

Comment: Can you say something more? Or give an example?